# Cannot parse Gradle Build file with Liquibase Configuration: Expression 'main' cannot be invoked as a function

Tags: kotlin, gradle, liquibase, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am relatively new to using Gradle over Maven, but I assumed it would be more fitting for a Kotlin project.

I am writing a Spring Boot application using a MySQL database and want to set up Liquibase for it. The project was initialized with Spring Initializr with the Liquibase dependency. I have added the (as far as I understand) necessary dependencies and the plugin that runs Liquibase when running the Spring Boot project. I also configured Liquibase in the Gradle build file as I found online. The Liquibase changelog file exists and seems valid; it only adds a single table with 2 columns.

When I try to build (or do anything with the Gradle wrapper), Gradle fails with

`Expression 'main' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found`

in the line of the configuration that contains "main" in my build file.

Here are the excerpts of my gradle.build.kts file that seem relevant:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.liquibase.gradle") version "2.2.1"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.23"
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
    runtimeOnly("com.mysql:mysql-connector-j")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "21"
    }
}


liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            changeLogFile = "some/url/to/changelog/yaml/file"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/someDatabase"
            username = "some-user"
            password = "some-password"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output from Gradle wrapper without the paths and line numbers:

```
$ ./gradlew build

> Configure project :
e: Expression 'main' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found
e: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public val NamedDomainObjectContainer<KotlinSourceSet>.main: NamedDomainObjectProvider<KotlinSourceSet> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
public val SourceSetContainer.main: NamedDomainObjectProvider<SourceSet> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
e: Unresolved reference: changeLogFile
e: Unresolved reference: url
e: Unresolved reference: username
e: Unresolved reference: password
```

When I run ./gradlew clean instead it fails the same way.
When I comment out the liquibase { ... } configuration block ./gradlew build runs fine and ./gradlew tasks lists the Liquibase-specific tasks.

Can someone explain why this is failing and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### A translation problem

It looks like you have a bit of a 'translation problem': you have written code suitable for the Groovy DSL (the other Gradle language) rather than for the Kotlin DSL.

When you write code within `activities {}`, you are running code that will execute in the scope of an object of type [`NamedDomainObjectContainer<Activity>`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer.html). These kind of containers are everywhere in Gradle (see discussion in [Kotlin DSL guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#kotdsl:containers)), and the `TaskContainer` (accessed via `tasks` in a build script) is probably the most common.

##### Groovy behaviour

When you write something like `main {}` you are calling a 'method', but one that is not defined in the class you are calling it on. In this situation in a Groovy Gradle build script for a `NamedDomainObjectContainer`, this is treated as the configuration of a domain object named `main`, which is created immediately if needed.

##### Kotlin approach

There is no such magic in Kotlin<sup>1</sup>. Being a statically typed language, you need to call methods that exist on the object in scope, or are extension methods for such an object (which may have been automatically created as a result of a plugin). The Kotlin DSL [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/kotlin-dsl/gradle/org.gradle.api/-named-domain-object-container/index.html) shows what is available natively.

In your case, what you want to do instead is to call [`register`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/kotlin-dsl/gradle/org.gradle.api/-named-domain-object-container/index.html#860734540%2FFunctions%2F-1793262594)<sup>2</sup>:

```
activities {
    register("main") {
        // do the configuration
    }
}
```

This is actually an improvement on the previous Groovy approach, because `register` configures `main` lazily and will not run the configuration code if and until `main` is required. (In fact, in optimal Groovy code you would end up writing code the same as the Kotlin in order to benefit from this lazy evaluation.)

---

<sup>1</sup> There is a different kind of magic in the Kotlin DSL, where sometimes objects defined in plugins trigger the generation of code, so you then *can* write code like the Groovy example. See [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#kotdsl:accessor_applicability). However I do not believe that is the case here.

<sup>2</sup> Assuming the `main` object has not been created, in which case you can call [`named`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/kotlin-dsl/gradle/org.gradle.kotlin.dsl/named.html)

Comment: I am not completely clear on the explanation because I haven't read up on Kotlin DSL (the configuration code was copied from some Liquibase documentation). That is not a problem with your explanation, obviously. I tried named() and register(); both get rid of the error (leaving me with the changeLogFile etc. errors), so this is the problem. I will come back to your answer again once I understand more about the topic. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it strange that I am still getting "Unresolved reference: changeLogFile" etc.? I would have assumed that the liquibase plugin is responsible for defining these fields and I should be able to set them.

Comment: I know nothing about Liquibase but you can look at what you're configuring in the `Activity` class ([GitHub](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/liquibase/gradle/Activity.groovy)). Here again you can see there is some Groovy magic: those parameters are not defined in the class but result in calls to `methodMissing`. To do the same in Kotlin, you'll need to reproduce what that does, ie `arguments["changeLogFile"] = "..."`

Comment: Thank you very much again. I'm slowly getting a grasp of it.

Comment: I don't think it's easy. A big reason I'm answering questions is the memory of the struggle I went through putting the pieces together.

Comment: I just didn't expect I'd have to parse implementation details of plugins to be able to configure them correctly. But I guess that's more or a problem with the plugin not having a lot of documentation than a problem with Gradle.